# Jquery подсветка одинаковых элементов в таблице

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Нашёл в jquery два интересных для меня события `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`, но столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.

У меня есть таблица и в ней я хочу выделить при наведении все ячейки с классом `.c1` другим цветом. Если убрать мышку, то цвет становится исходным. Также есть ячейки с классами `.c2(3,4,...,16)`, которые я также хотел бы изменять при наведении. Но у меня получился очень громоздкий код. Возможно его как-то сократить?

Кусок кода:

```
$(".c1").mouseenter(function(){$(".c1").addClass("h")});
$(".c1").mouseleave(function(){$(".c1").removeClass("h")});
$(".c2").mouseenter(function(){$(".c2").addClass("h")});
$(".c2").mouseleave(function(){$(".c2").removeClass("h")});
$(".c3").mouseenter(function(){$(".c3").addClass("h")});
$(".c3").mouseleave(function(){$(".c3").removeClass("h")});
```

Важно! Если ячейка имеет класс `.c1`, то ко всем ячейкам с классом `.c1` добавится/удалится класс `.h`.

Пробовал `$(".c1,.c2,.c3")`, но в таком случае выделялись все ячейки независимо на какую я наводил `c1` или `c2`.

Буду Вам очень признателен, если поможете! Заранее прошу прощения у *администрации*, если данный вопрос был (по поиску я ничего не нашёл, пробовал разные варианты).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с назначением активного класса таблице. В этом случае можно легко и гибко менять варианты подсветки ячеек.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#table td')
      .mouseenter(function(){
        var $td = $(this)
        $td.closest('table').removeClass().addClass('hover_' + $td.attr('class'))
      })
      .mouseleave(function(){
        var $td = $(this)
        $td.closest('table').removeClass()
      })
});
```

```css
#table.hover_c1 td.c1 {
  background-color: #f00;
}
#table.hover_c2 td.c2 {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
#table.hover_c3 td.c3 {
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="c1">c1</td>
    <td class="c2">c2</td>
    <td class="c3">c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="c1">c1</td>
    <td class="c2">c2</td>
    <td class="c3">c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="c1">c1</td>
    <td class="c2">c2</td>
    <td class="c3">c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Видимо не совсем поняли. У меня есть таблица:
`<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="c1">c1</td>
    <td class="price">цена</td>
    <td class="result">результат</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="c2">c2</td>
    <td class="price">цена</td>
    <td class="result">результат</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="price">цена</td>
    <td class="c1">c1</td>
    <td class="result">результат</td>
  </tr>
</table>` и расположение c1, c2 ... постоянно меняется (не обязательно первая в после tr. А если использовать ваш код, то все классы стираются.

Comment: Данные пример будет работать и стой таблицей, что Вы сейчас привели. Классы меняются только у таблицы. Если Вы опишите задачу еще более конкретней, возможно мы найдем решение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но, повозившись, я разобрался с Вашим кодом. И ещё раз спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td[class^="c"]').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("h")
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("h")
});
```

оно?